# The server cannot process the request because of Spring MVC <form:select>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a formular in order to populate some entities. I run into problems when I am trying to POST a form which contains a Spring MVC `<form:select>` field.
In Eclipse I do not receive any error or warning message, while in the browser I get a http status 400 - Bad Request.

> Type Status Report
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Extra explanations:
I have a StudentDetails entity which contains 2 fields that I am interested in at the moment, Classroom classroom and ParentsDetails parentsDetails.
The Classroom objects are already created and all of them will be stored in a LinkedHashMap<Classroom, String> as a model attribute (i am doing this in the saveAccountDetails method from the Controller).
The ParentsDetails object will be created after the StudentDetails entity will be saved with the selected classroom.

When I submit the form as I mentioned above I run into an error but without any(or relevant) error message.

I spent some time debugging and trying different approaches of handling that map of Classrooms, but none of them worked.
What is actually happening, the controller method saveStudentDetails is not called anymore.
The issue must come from that form:select because if I get rid of this input, the controller method will be called and will let me advance in creating the ParentsDetails entity.

I have no clue what is wrong.
I used previously this form:select but the LinkedHashMap contained just Strings, without any objects and it worked. I think thats my issue.

StudentDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_details")
public class StudentDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="current_year_of_study")
    private Integer currentYearOfStudy;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parents_details_id")
    private ParentsDetails parentsDetails;
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="class_id")
    private Classroom classroom;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="studentDetails", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private User user;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="course_studentdetails",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_details_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id")
            )
    private List<Course> courses;

... (Constructors, getters setters)
```

Controller.java

```
    @PostMapping("/save-account-details")
    public String saveAccountDetails(@ModelAttribute("theAccountDetails") AccountDetails theAccountDetails, @RequestParam("userUsername") String username, Model theModel) {
        User theUser = userService.getUser(username);
        theUser.setAccountDetails(theAccountDetails);
        accountDetailsService.saveAccountDetails(theAccountDetails);
        userService.saveUser(theUser);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        theModel.addAttribute("theStudentDetails", new StudentDetails());
        theModel.addAttribute("classroomsList", classroomService.getSchoolClassrooms(theUser.getAccountDetails().getCity()));
        theModel.addAttribute("entity", "StudentDetails");
        return "create-user";
    }
    @PostMapping("/save-student-details")
    public String saveStudentDetails(@ModelAttribute("theStudentDetails") StudentDetails theStudentDetails, @RequestParam("userUsername") String username, Model theModel) {
        User theUser = userService.getUser(username);
        theUser.setStudentDetails(theStudentDetails);
        studentDetailsService.saveStudentDetails(theStudentDetails);
        userService.saveUser(theUser);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        theModel.addAttribute("theParentsDetails", new ParentsDetails());
        theModel.addAttribute("entity", "ParentsDetails");
        return "create-user";
    }
    @PostMapping("/save-parents-details")
    public String saveParentsDetails(@ModelAttribute("theParentsDetails") ParentsDetails theParentsDetails, @RequestParam("userUsername") String username, Model theModel) {
        User theUser = userService.getUser(username);
        theUser.getStudentDetails().setParentsDetails(theParentsDetails);
        parentsDetailsService.saveParentsDetails(theParentsDetails);
        userService.saveUser(theUser);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        theModel.addAttribute("theParentsDetails", new ParentsDetails());
        theModel.addAttribute("entity", "ParentsDetails");
        return "create-user";
    }
```

create-user.jsp

```
<c:if test="${entity == 'StudentDetails'}">
                        <c:url var="saveStudentDetails" value="save-student-details">
                            <c:param name="userUsername" value="${theUser.username}" />
                        </c:url>
                        <form:form action="${saveStudentDetails}" modelAttribute="theStudentDetails" method="POST">
                            <form:hidden path="id" />
                            <div class="form-area">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Current Year of Study</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="currentYearOfStudy" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Classroom</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:select path="classroom" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                        <form:option value="" label="Select classroom..." />
                                        <form:options items="${classroomsList}" />
                                    </form:select>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form:form>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${entity == 'ParentsDetails'}">
                        <c:url var="saveParentsDetails" value="save-parents-details">
                            <c:param name="userUsername" value="${theUser.username}" />
                        </c:url>
                        <form:form action="${saveParentsDetails}" modelAttribute="theParentsDetails" method="POST">
                            <form:hidden path="id" />
                            <div class="form-area">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Father First Name</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="fatherFirstName" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Father Last Name</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="fatherLastName" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Father Telephone</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="fatherTelephone" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Mother First Name</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="motherFirstName" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Mother Last Name</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="motherLastName" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Mother Telephone</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="motherTelephone" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form:form>
                    </c:if>
```

If any more code snippets are needed, I will add them as soon as possible. Thank you in advance!

[image: Network tab]

This is the network tab. The object looks like it was submitted with the form...
I will add shortly a video with the application.

Edit: demo link: https://youtu.be/neJOLHL9REo

Comment: Would you add some logging to see if the method `saveParentsDetails` was called?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis yes I put a System.out.println() as the first line in that method, but i receive no print in the console... Thats why i assumed the controller method is not called at all..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **multipart form-data** to enctype in the form tag, it may works.

FROM:

```
<form:form action="${saveStudentDetails}" 
modelAttribute="theStudentDetails" method="POST">
```

TO:

```
<form:form action="${saveStudentDetails}" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
modelAttribute="theStudentDetails" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion, but unfortunately it has the same behaviour...

Comment: To investigate 404, hit the endpoint using postman and check

Comment: Also use name="inputGroupSelect01" in <form:select > instead of Id